# How to force sound (bluetooth) output to be active on macOS

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a problem with my bluetooth headphones where the connection goes inactive (within a few seconds) if there is no sound output from my Mac. When I play sound again, it takes a few seconds before the audio starts working again. If there is no sound in about a minute, they turn off completely.

This is most definitely an issue with my headphones, but since they are no longer being produced or maintained I find help from the manufacturer very unlikely.

I've managed to work around this problem by always having music playing at a very low (inaudible) volume. Now they stay connected, all the time.

Out of curiosity, is there another (less silly) way I can force the bluetooth connection / audio to stay active all the time?